# How to remove a particular route in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I want to get a particular named route from the navigation stack and remove it using  Navigator.removeRoute(context, **route**); but how can I get **route**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. can you be more specific by giving example, what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This works...

```
Navigator.removeRoute(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThePage()));
```

You have to specify the `Route` you want to remove not the name

***Example***

```
var page2Route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2());
var page3Route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page3());

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 1"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, page2Route);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 2"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, page3Route);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 3"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        label: Text("Remove Page 2"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.removeRoute(
              context, page2Route);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Not working. Getting this error: Failed assertion: line 2185 pos 12: 'route._navigator == this': is not true. Can you share an example if you've done something like this?

Comment: Did you use MaterialPageRoute to navigate?

Comment: Yes. I have used MaterialPageRoute

Comment: @BhoomiPrajapati The route which you are trying to remove from the backstack must be present in the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

Navigator.pushReplacement

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewScreen()));
```

This method does not remove the route.
But it does not send the page it belongs to the stack while pushing

Answer (score -1):

The following code snipet can help you if you are using GetX navigations.

Get.removeRoute(Get.rawRoute)

Comment: The original post is about Flutter navigation, not GetX