# How can I replace a route below so I don't have duplicate routes in my navigator stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code inside my Navigator Bloc

```
  @override
  Stream<dynamic> mapEventToState(NavigatorEvent event) async* {
    final navigatorState = navigatorKey.currentState;
    if (navigatorState == null) return;

    if (event is NavigateToProfileEvent) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        navigatorState.replaceRouteBelow(anchorRoute: ProfilePage.route(), newRoute: ProfilePage.route());
      });
    }
  }
```

and this is the route in my profile page

```
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() {
    return InstantMaterialPageRoute<ProfilePage>(builder: (_) => ProfilePage());
  }
```

But it throws the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4961 pos 12: 'anchorRoute._navigator == this': is not true.
```

I want to prevent duplicate routes. So let's say you have the following stack

Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3 > Page 4 > Page 2 > Page 4 > Page 3

I want it to become

Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 4 > Page 3

Comment: i Think you want some like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61612394/6813907 then you can Push new route

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the same page you want to push, you could do:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, route);
```

Which will pop current page and then push it.

Also if you would like to send some data to it, you could try with:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, route, arguments: myParam);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer but my example was explicitly showing that I am not on the same route. So this is not the answer to my question I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

from
`Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3 > Page 4 > Page 2 > Page 4 > Page 3`
to
`Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 4 > Page 3`

I guess you need this:
For `Page 1` and `Page 2`, in your page stack, the newer can not replace older.
For `Page 3` and `Page 4`, in your stack, the newer will replace older.

Then you can do some `removeRoute` things when you push to a new Page.
When you push to a new page, you can check your stack and remove newer `Page 1` and `Page 2`.
When you push to a new `Page 3` or `Page 4`, you can do some  `replaceRouteBelow` or `removeRouteBelow` things.

But anyway, my suggestion is, `Navigator.popAndPushNamed` and `Navigator.popAndPushNamed` really better.