# How to close the specified page in flutter

Tags: flutter, router, navigator

Open the app, the page order is A->B->C, I want to close the B page on the C page, and the page order is A->C.
As far as I know, `Navigator.removeRoute(context, routerC)` can be used, but I don't know how to get routerC.

Can you tell me how to do it? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a particular route in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611995/how-to-remove-a-particular-route-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

route list class

```
  class AppRoutes {
  static String get A=> "/a";
  static String get B=> "/b";
  static String get C=> "/c";
  static String get K=> "/k";
```

write remove route function as below

```
clearRouteAndOpen(BuildContext context, String name,
    {Object? arguments, String? removeUntil}) {
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context, name, ModalRoute.withName(removeUntil ?? name),
      arguments: arguments);
}
```

call removeRoute function as below when back press in toolbar or any action you can remove B easily from C. call below function from C screen. Suppose A start from K screen. just remove until K.

```
 clearRouteAndOpen(
                          context,
                          AppRoutes.A,
                          removeUntil: AppRoutes.K,
                        );
```